# Iframe with HREF=pageid

Tags: html, iframe

It's easy to code something like this in an IFRAME:

```
                 <a href="PA079.html">June 2016 - September 2016</a><br/>
```

and have it go to PA079 when this is clicked. However (obviously) it executes within the Iframe space. I would like to have it execute in the main window instead. In other word I want PA079 to replace whatever the current active page is. None of the _TARGET options seems to work - I get a "file not found" kind of exception.

My ultimate goal is to have an index to pages in my website that points to a number of pages and is in each of those pages. I don't want to have to modify every program each time I add another one to the list. This Iframe seemed promising.
Here's the gist of the code-
In the main page:

```
`<div class="sidebar">`
`Index to this article:`
`<p>`
`<iframe title="Inline Frame Example" height="75%" width="100%"` 
`frameborder="0" marginwidth="0"` 
`scrolling="auto"  src="IndexNews2.html" class="sidebarIndex" `allowfullscreen> `
`</iframe>    </div>`
`<div class="article">`
```

(the rest of the story on the main body)

CSS for class "sidebar" is

```
`.sidebar { background-color: cyan;`
    `padding:8px;`
    `width:180px; `
    `float:left;`
    `font-size:.8em;`
    `overflow:scroll;`
    `height:80%;`
    `border: 2px black solid;`
        ` }`
```

finally, IndexNews2.html is

```
`<a href="PA075.html target="_top">December 2014 - May 2015 </a><br/>`
`<a href="PA077.html#target="_blank">June 2015 - November 2015</a><br/>`
`<a href="PA078.html target="???">December 2015 -May 2016</a><br/>`
`<a href="PA079.html#h1">June 2016 - September 2016</a><br/>`
`<a href="PA080.html">October 2016 - January 2017</a><br/>`
```

PA075 gets "file not found"
PA077 works but displays in the IFrame space
PA078 gets "file not found"
PA079 I believe actually points to "h1" in PA079, but again displays in the IFrame.
PA080 displays in the IFrame.

If I've not been clear what I want: if I click on the PA075 line it will execute PA075 full screen in this same window. That is, it will completely replace the existing page with PA075.

Comment: "file not found" usually means the file ("PA079.html") doesn't exist.

Comment: Well,yes. PA079.html DOES exist, and it DOES find it, as the html is written above, but it opens it in the IFrame space.. What it does NOT find is PA079.html target="_top" or "_self" or "_blank" or anything else.

Comment: How are you adding the target attribute?  Put the code you tried in the question.

Comment: added the significant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the misplaced quotation marks.  `target` is a *separate* attribute from `href`; it shouldn't be placed inside the `href` value.

Fixed example:

```html
<a href="PA075.html" target="_top">December 2014 - May 2015 </a><br/>
<a target="_blank" href="PA077.html">June 2015 - November 2015</a><br/>
```

(Note that the order `target` and `href` appear in doesn't matter, so long as they are both present.)

Comment: Actually, either statement will work as a STANDALONE statement, as will '<a href="PA075.html target="_blank">June 2015 - November 2015</a>' with the TARGET in the HREF . PA075 will execute in a new tab. I believe you are correct in that putting the TARGET separate from the HREF will work in an IFrame. Thanks for that answer. I still have some problems with my standard page formatting, but I've wasted WAY too much time on this already.

Comment: @woody8747 Having an odd number of quotation marks in the HREF isn't even valid HTML.  I guess the browser's error correction might be correctly guessing what you want with the `a`, but not with the `iframe`.

Comment: At this point I've done all I'm going to do with this. Is there some way I can mark this complete or answered?

Comment: @woody8747 Yes, click the checkmark symbol to the left of the answer.